# Why does the function still remove the substring just once and not anymore in the newly formed string after the removal?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that removes a specified substring from a string. I attempted changing the loops, but the function still only removes the substring once and not anymore in the newly formed string after the removal. What could be causing this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* izbaci_tekst(char* str, const char* tekst, int cs){
    int i,j,k;
    int str_len=strlen(str);
    int tekst_len=strlen(tekst);
    if (tekst_len==0){
        return str;
    }
    for(i=0;i<str_len-tekst_len+1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<tekst_len;j++){
            if(cs==0){
                if(tolower(str[i+j])!=tolower(tekst[j]))
                    break;
            }
            else {
                if(str[i+j]!=tekst[j]){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(j==tekst_len){
            for(k=i;k<str_len-tekst_len;k++){
                str[k]=str[k+tekst_len];
            }
            str_len-=tekst_len;
            i--;
        }
    }
    str[str_len]='\0';
    return str;
}

int main() {
    printf("Print");
    return 0;
}
```

For this case,

```
Result: Incorrect result
Test code:
char niz[] = "aaaabcbcbcbc";
printf("'%s'", izbaci_tekst(niz, "abc", 1));
Program input/output:
Expected output(s):     ''
                     
Your program outputted: 'aaabcbcbc'.
```

Comment: First, each function should do only one thing, yours is doing two - removing a string, and searching for strings to remove. Split your function into two, it'll be easier to test and debug them separately.

Comment: I would suggest you want a function which removes one occurrence of the substring. Or doesn't remove it. Return an int value to indicate which happened. Then a second function which just iteratively applies that operation unit it returns `0` indicating no removals occurred.

Comment: You need to move further back after you remove the substring. After removing `"abc"` from `"aaaabcbcbcbc"` and decrementing `i` you are pointing to `'b'` in the next iteration. You need to move back by `tekst_len+1`.

Comment: Second, I'm guessing from the example the requirement is to scan the string from the beginning each time a substring is removed. You're scanning from the location of the string that was removed, so for "aaabcbcbc" when you remove the first match, you continue scanning "aabcbc" from the "b", and won't find the newly created "abc".

Comment: What does the parameter `cs` do?

Comment: "case sensitive"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite hard to read as you try to do everything in one function

I would split it into functions which do some specific tasks. Then the function itself is trivial. I did not write a `strlen` equivalent as it is a trivial task

```
/**
banned conetent removed
 */
int strneq(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n, int cs)
{
    char c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
    while(n-- && *s1 && *s2)
    {
        if(cs)
        {
            c1 = *s1;
            c2 = *s2;
        }
        else
        {
            c1 = tolower(*s1);
            c2 = tolower(*s2);
        }
        if(c1 != c2) break;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return !(c1 == c2);
}

/**

banned conetent removed
 */
/*  $OpenBSD: strstr.c,v 1.5 2005/08/08 08:05:37 espie Exp $ */
/*-
 * Copyright (c) 1990 The Regents of the University of California.
 * All rights reserved.
 */
char *mystrstr(const char *s, const char *find, int cs)
{
    char c, sc;
    size_t len;
    if ((c = *find++) != 0) {
        len = strlen(find);
        do {
            do {
                if ((sc = *s++) == 0)
                    return (NULL);
            } while (sc != c);
        } while (strneq(s, find, len, cs) != 0);
        s--;
    }
    return ((char *)s);
}

/**
banned conetent removed
 */
char *strrem(char *haystack, const char *needle, int cs)
{
    size_t nlen = strlen(needle);
    char *current;
    while((current = mystrstr(haystack, needle, cs)))
    {
        while((*current = *(current + nlen))) current++;
    }
    return haystack;
}

int main(void)
{
    char h[] = "aaaabcbcbcbc";
    char *n = "abc";

    printf("'%s'\n", strrem(h,n,1));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/91no5Pn3b

(Doxygen comments generated by AI) - removed

Comment: The AI-generated comments do nothing to improve the code, may fall afoul of SO's policies, and this does not address the actual issue with the OP's code. Suggesting a better approach is fine, but if the core question hasn't been answered, it should be first.

Comment: @Chris your comment is outdated.  I asked the question on meta and removed them

Comment: I'm (super) curious about the "banned content removed" comments.  Can you please tell me a little/hint about the nature of the banned content (without explicitly saying it so you don't get banned or something)? -- thx

Comment: I use AI to generate doxygen content - and I thought that comments are allowed. But they are not.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental mistake you've made is to not restart your eraure at the beginning of the string after each removal of the substring. If we consider the example provided:

```
aaaabcbcbcbc
```

You iterate through until you see that `abc` can be found starting at index 3, and you remove it which gives you:

```
aaabcbcbc
```

But now if you continue from index 3, you're just considering:

```
bcbcbc
```

And we can see that `abc` never again occurs within that string so no erasure occurs.

Let's instead use *your logic* to create a function that explicitly erases just one occurrence of a substring from a string and indicates whether it has by returning `0` or `1`. We can then run that in a loop in another function until it runs `0`. This handles resetting back to the beginning of the string after each erasure without having to complicate the `erase_once` function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

enum CaseSensitive {
    CASE_SENS,
    CASE_INSENS
};

int erase_once(char *str, const char *substr, enum CaseSensitive cs) {
    size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    size_t substr_len = strlen(substr);

    if (str_len < substr_len || substr_len == 0) return 0;

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < str_len - substr_len + 1; i++) {
        int match_found = 1;

        for (size_t j = i; j < i + substr_len; j++) {
            if ((cs == CASE_INSENS &&
                 tolower(str[j]) != tolower(substr[j-i])) ||
                str[j] != substr[j-i]) {
                match_found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!match_found) continue;

        for (; i < str_len - substr_len; i++) {
            str[i] = str[i + substr_len];
        }
        str[i] = '\0';

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int erase(char *str, const char *substr, enum CaseSensitive cs) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; erase_once(str, substr, cs); i++);
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    char s1[] = "aaabcbcbc";
    const char *s2 = "abc";

    erase(s1, s2, CASE_INSENS);
    printf("%s\n", s1);
}
```

When we run this we're basically running:

```
erase("aaabcbcbc", "abc", CASE_INSENS);
erase("aabcbc", "abc", CASE_INSENS);
erase("abc", "abc", CASE_INSENS);
erase("", "abc", CASE_INSENS);
```